# how to make disable or unvisible email link when the it is clicked, also, how can i use general smtp server?

Tags: c#, email

I tried some codes but after it is send to mail account, it is always the active how can it become  passive link .

```
                   string UName = GetNewValidationCode();
                    // Now lets create an email message
                    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");

        var mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress("bilkentliaslan@windowslive.com");
        mail.To.Add(TextBox6.Text);
        mail.Subject = "Registration";
        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string htmlBody;
        htmlBody = string.Format("Thank you for creating an account with YourDomain.com</ br>"+"Please click the below link to activate your account <br />"+"<a href='http://localhost:2386/ActivateUser.aspx?userName{0}&Id={1}'>Activate {0} </a>", UName, user_name);
        mail.Body = htmlBody;

        SmtpServer.Port = 587;
        SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("bilkentliaslan@windowslive.com", "my password");
        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
        SmtpServer.Send(mail);

                    // Redirecto to What ever page
                    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
```

Comment: Are you trying to disable the link while your code is processing or do you want each user to only be able to click the link once?

Comment: What do you mean by 'active' and 'passive' link?

Comment: 1. Get your wordings proper.

2. Use the `using` statement to free the resources, if thats what u mean.

3. Two questions should be two questions, not one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a table that stores the waiting IDs, i.e., the IDs that you have sent an email about, but which are not yet activated.

Then in the code of your `ActivateUser.aspx` (actually in the back-end code that that page then calls), check if the row exists, perform the user activation work and then remove the row from the table. If the user then goes to the very same URL again later, the row won't be there and the user won't be (re-)activated.

Comment: You can upvote and/or accept the answer if you are satisfied with it... Thanks!